# Initializing a userform class

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform created and several buttons (the number will be set during runtime) in excel. When clicked, each button will open its own version of the userform (same userform but each button will have its own userform, for example: button1 will open userform1, button2 will open userform2, etc. with each userform being the same userform class).

I am thinking of somehow creating a userform class and each button will instantiate a userform object.

I'm just not sure what the proper code/syntax is to achieve this.

Comment: i may be naive, but I would think you'd need to reference each particular userform as a separate instance...  are you talking about creating a userform on the fly each time a button is clicked, based off the class module?

Comment: sorry if I'm using the wrong terminology...I'm just learning VBA. I have a userform created in the visual basic editor. When a user clicks the button in excel, a userform object will be created and the user can interact with this userform. Clicking another button will create another userform object of the same userform "class". Essentially the same layout, appearence, etc. but the data that is filled out in the userform belongs to that "button". Dunno if this is still really vague or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may help, based on your last comment.

Just create one user form. Then create a function that opens the userform and fills the specific data with parameterized variables. Then for each button call the pass the variable into the function. Something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()

load_user_form "Handy", "Code"

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click()

load_user_form "different", "data"

End Sub

Function load_user_form(strField1 as String, strField2 as String)

userForm.Show
userForm.TextBox1.Value = strField1
userForm.textBox2.value = strfield2
End Function
```

This code may not be spot on, but it will get you there.

Comment: thanks! I think I can use this as a starting point for a solution